# Debugging php with gdb

Tags: php, debugging, segmentation-fault, debug

I am attempting to debug a SIGSEGV on PHP on my Ubuntu 9.10.

I've installed `php5-dbg` to have the debug symbols available, however, when I start gdb, it shows the following output:

```
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/php...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/php5...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Type, /usr/bin/php -v in terminal,does it say: (DEBUG) in the top version line (at the end).If there is no such line, that's the problem you didn't install php5-dbg correctly

Comment: It's not there, though I installed everything through Synaptic... I even reinstalled to no avail.... Kinda weird... any ideas for this behavior?

Comment: I tried to reproduce on my system, but got debug with php5-dbg.  You might try apt-get purge of some packages?

Comment: Related: [How to get current PHP function name in gdb?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/9558/12021)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under certain situations, the `-dbg` packages don't work correctly. Instead, try the `-dbgsym` packages, available from the separate "debug symbols" repository:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

However, when trying this locally with Ubuntu 9.10, I have no problem loading symbols using the existing `php5-dbg` package. Perhaps make sure you have the latest updates installed first, and then try it?

As an example:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.php
<?php sleep(10); ?>
$ gdb php
...
(gdb) run /tmp/test.php
...
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0xf7fe0430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7fe0430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf7a13b50 in nanosleep () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#2  0xf7a13991 in sleep () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#3  0x081fbfc1 in zif_sleep (ht=1, return_value=0x866d204, 
    return_value_ptr=0x0, this_ptr=0x0, return_value_used=0)
    at /build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/ext/standard/basic_functions.c:4787
#4  0x082f9616 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0xffffafbc)
    at /build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:200
#5  0x082f511b in execute (op_array=0x866d7f0)
    at /build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:92
#6  0x082cf414 in zend_execute_scripts (type=8, retval=0x0, file_count=3)
    at /build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/Zend/zend.c:1215
#7  0x08284166 in php_execute_script (primary_file=0xffffd454)
    at /build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/main/main.c:2046
#8  0x08352c38 in main (argc=2, argv=0xffffd554)
    at /build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/sapi/cli/php_cli.c:1170
```

Comment: That did the trick. I don't know why it wouldn't work with the other package! Thanks!